# Delete all rows from a MYSQL table except TOP/BOTTOM 50 rows

Tags: mysql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d21f3/1

I have a table with some entries here, I want to keep only 50 messages in this table sorted by `message_id`, and **DELETE** the rest of entries.

Please help me with the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have to keep 50 from top and 50 from bottom? && or ||?

Comment: I have to keep top 50 messages only, based on their message_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g..

```
DELETE a 
  FROM chat_history a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.message_id 
         FROM chat_history x 
         JOIN chat_history y 
           ON y.message_id >= x.message_id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.message_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <= 50
     ) b 
    ON b.message_id = a.message_id 
 WHERE b.message_id IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/361b4/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one  i have used `ORDER BY message_id DESC` change it as you want it will delete all except the seleted 50 entries, i have aliased the query because you cannot use same table to select  with delete operation

```
DELETE FROM `chat_history` WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT t.id FROM 
(SELECT id FROM chat_history ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 50 ) t)
```

Comment: Would `DELETE FROM chat_history WHERE MESSAGE_ID < (SELECT MESSAGE_ID FROM chat_history ORDER BY MESSAGE_ID DESC LIMIT 50,1)` be quicker?

Comment: Yup it will be quicker but op has not mentioned the desired order asc of desc and one thing you cannot use same table in select when performing the delete operation

Comment: No, it is not allowing DELETE and SELECT in the same query, I thought of using NOT IN, but i'm unable to use it together.

Comment: @ahsanzaheer see  my updated query with aliased table